# When three standard dice are tossed, the numbers a,b,c are obtained. Find the probability that abc = 1

Tags: combinatorics

When three standard dice are tossed, the numbers a,b,c are obtained. Find the probability that abc = 1

I think the answer is 1/216 since the probability of getting the number 1 is 1/6 and you have 3 chances so 1/6times1/6times1/6 is the probability(1/216)

Better Solution: $abc = 1$ only when $a=b=c= 1$. The probability that $a=1$ is $\frac16$. Therefore, the probability that $a,b,c$ are all 1 is $\left(\frac16\right)^3 = \boxed{\frac1{216}}$.

Comment: Yes, you only need to add that, since $a,b,c\ge 1$, then $abc=1 \iff a=b=c=1$.

Comment: You can type `$\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{216}$` to obtain $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{216}$.